# How do I import a Material Web Component in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I followed the standard [tutorial in sveltkit](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#introduction-getting-started) to create a Typescript Project for a basic template.

I wanted to use [Material Web Component Button](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/tree/master/packages/button).

I `npm install @material/mwc-button`.

Then I simply add the following to `routes/index.svelte`

```
<script>
    import "@material/mwc-button";
</script>
```

To which I get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

This is driving me crazy as it's step one of my requirement and this is week 3 of being stuck. I don't know even where to start. Is this a vite problem, sveltekit problem, mwc problem? Any advice would be amazing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wow, that error message is very unhelpful. In a non-TS SvelteKit project, you get `Error when evaluating SSR module /node_modules/lit-html/lib/template-result.js: ReferenceError: window is not defined`, which is a little clearer about what is going on.

Importing Material Web Components runs code that uses `window`, which is not available on the server. Because of this, Vite throws an error while trying to process the imported `mwc-button` library. You can use a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) in Svelte's [onMount](https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount) lifecycle function so that the library is only imported on the client. You will have to do this with any web component you import.

```html
<script>
    import { onMount} from 'svelte';
    onMount(async () => {
        await import('@material/mwc-button');
    })
</script>

<mwc-button>Button</mwc-button>
```

For further reference, see the "How do I use a client-side only library that depends on document or window?" question in the [SvelteKit FAQ](https://kit.svelte.dev/faq#integrations-how-do-i-use-a-client-side-only-library-that-depends-on-document-or-window).

Comment: This is a similar solution I came to when I faced this issue, one problem though that I am experiencing is that there is a significant delay between the page loading and the web components loading. Because although the page returns from the server fully hydrated, the web components won't import until the code gets to this point on the client side. Is there a way to include the import in the header maybe?